# C++ export into HTML with dates

Tags: c++

I have probably simple problem for u. Hello.

I´ve written a function to count exact date of Easter in the year which someone will put in. So for example somebody puts in 2016 and he will get out sentence like "Easter will be 26.03.2016" .. If he will put in more years, like "2016, 2017, 2020 - 2024", he will get exact days of Easter in these years. But what I need to do is get these dates from C++ to HTML file dates.html .. Can somebody give me advice how to do it? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file (using for example `ofstream`), and write the html to that.

Answer (score 0):

Show us some code and what you have already tried. Also take a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/). It is a simply guide about `if/ofstream` and file-handling in C++.